# Getting the Exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException when trying to serialize a JSON array

Tags: c#, json, list, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON array in the format such as below

```
[
    {
        "Id": 111,
        "Name": "ABC"

    },
    {
        "Id": 222,
        "Name": "CDE"
    },
    {
        "Id": 333,
        "Name": "EFG"
    }
]
```

I Have the class

```
public class IDInformation
    {
        public List<IDInformation> ID{ get; set; }
    }
```

and I am trying to use it here where I am getting the Exception

**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException**

```
var details= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <IDInformation>(File);
```

I tried some of the fixes on some other SO questions as well but couldn't quite get what I wanted ..

What I am rying to do here is store all the ID in each of the separate JSON objects in a List (For example I want to iterate through this file and store 111,222,333 in a List )

Would really appreciate some help if anyone has come across something like this before.

Comment: Use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate classes for your JSON. You need a class with `Id` and `Name` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have following class to be able to deserialize the JSON successfully.

```
public class IDInformation
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON to a collection of IDInformation as following.

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<IDInformation>>(File);
```

From the list you can further create collection of ID of all the objects in the list as following.

```
var idList = list.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

This will give you collection of integer values populated by `Id` values from the JSON array.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the help. Understood where my mistake was

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're getting is because it cannot deserialize the json into your `IDInformation` class.

Change your `IDInformation` class to:

```
public class IDInformation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like so:

```
var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IDInformation>>(File);
```

Note how the field name `Id` matches the Json `Id` field.

Comment: `Name` is missing from your class though?

Comment: I might be mistaken but off the top of my head you do not need every json field in your class - so if you were not interested in `Name` you could just omit it from your class altogether.